# Dragging and dropping from Catalog Favorites of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, drag-and-drop, catalog-pane

I'm slowly transitioning from **ArcMap** to **ArcGIS Pro** (2.3.0) and I'm facing a quite frustrating UX problem:

I can't drag and drop layers from the Catalog pane to the map if it comes from the **Favorites** menu. I have to right-click on it > Add to current map.

[image]

Oddly, drag and drop works with layers from folder connections created in the **Project** tab but those folder connections are linked to the project so you have to recreate them for every project.

It might not seem like a big issue but it's one of the little things that bother you when you work all day with this software. I just wanted to check if this is the same for any of you, or if someone found a way to solve it (maybe with a newer version?).

Comment: You should add that functionality to the ArcGIS Ideas page on GeoNet! Nice catch. My answer is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same in Pro 2.4.2.

**A work around** is right-click the folder you want to have around and select "Add to New Projects". It will then show up under all new Projects' "Folder" section.

A plus is that you can get to it from both the **Catalog Pane** *AND* **Catalog View**. The "Favorites" tab is only available in Catalog Pane. For that reason alone I usually only use Catalog View.

That way it's always in your projects AND others can see it too (that could be desired or undesired). In that way, it's a kind of like a 'favorite' folder. You can always remove it from Projects it gets added to if it turns out you don't want it there.

Comment: Great work around, I didn't noticed this option, thanks ;) About the Catalog View, I'm able to see the Favorites too (see here: https://i.imgur.com/L2NHK0H.png)

Comment: @LéoM That's right! You can see it from that drop down or the Contents pane of the Catalog View. So many choices!